# Why can't I get the man page of the crypt function?

Tags: encryption, manpage

On my Fedora system, I can do `man 3 crypt` and I see the man page of the crypt function.

However, when I do the same on Ubuntu it gives me:

```
No manual entry for crypt in section 3
```

I know that it has to be somewhere because it is the function that does the encryption for user password and I even found the man pages here:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man3/crypt.3.html

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.1 Bionic LTS

Comment: Works fine on my machine. Have you made any changes to your manpages or maybe uninstalled any packages?

Comment: no, i will try to patch it and see what's up

Comment: I patched it didn't work, i just downloaded the man pages and put it in /usr/share/man/man3/

Answer (score 2):

While the `mcrypt` package provides a Section 1 manual page for the `crypt` executable command, the Section 3 page (covering the `crypt` library function) is provided by the `manpages-dev` package:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/man/man1/crypt.1.gz /usr/share/man/man3/crypt.3.gz
mcrypt: /usr/share/man/man1/crypt.1.gz
manpages-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/crypt.3.gz
```